# Magento 2 product custom options name and storeview scope

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I have a M2 store (2.1.0) with 2 storeviews. When I change the name of a product custom option (not a product attribute) in storeview A, the name in storeview B is also changed.

Very similiar to https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-Feature-Requests-and/Product-custom-option-price-scope-issue/idi-p/44973, but not with the price but the option name.

How can I fix that?

Thanks!